# How to ask Meteor build code for old nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor

The Wekan code that be built by Meteor cannot run in node 0.10.4x ,
Meteor will create the code for new version node, like const or lambda expression.
How to ask Meteor to build the code that can be run in node 0.10.4x ?

Error 1:

```
/home/wekan/output/bundle/programs/server/packages/modules.js:33433
const Boom = require(‘boom’);
^^^^^
SyntaxError: Use of const in strict mode.
at /home/wekan/output/bundle/programs/server/boot.js:292:30
at Array.forEach (native)
at Function..each..forEach (/home/wekan/output/bundle/programs/server/node_modules/underscore/underscore.js:79:11)
at /home/wekan/output/bundle/programs/server/boot.js:133:
```

Error 2:

```
/home/wekan/output/bundle/programs/server/packages/modules.js:33571
credentialsFunc(attributes.id, (err, credentials) => {
^Preformatted text
SyntaxError: Unexpected token >
at /home/wekan/output/bundle/programs/server/boot.js:292:30
at Array.forEach (native)
at Function..each..forEach (/home/wekan/output/bundle/programs/server/node_modules/underscore/underscore.js:79:11)
at /home/wekan/output/bundle/programs/server/boot.js:133:5
```

Comment: Wekan can only run in node.js in 0.10.4x

Comment: This wekan: https://github.com/wekan/wekan?

Comment: Yes, but my Wekan is 0.10.1, only for node 0.10.4x. The current version is 0.47.

Comment: It can be solved by coping old node_modules to my Wekan project, the built code is runable for node 0.10.46. But it means that I cannot update my node_modules anymore.

Answer (score 3):

According to the Wekan documentation at https://github.com/wekan/wekan/wiki/Install-and-Update

> If you haven't already, you need to install Node.js, given that we
>   need node version 4.8.4, make sure to either use the custom packages
>   (the ones of your OS are likely too old) or install the correct
>   version from the Node.js website.

Node 0.10.4 is pretty old already, I don't know why you are still using it. You can use something like nvm if you want to manage different versions of node on your machine.

Comment: The Wekan you show is new version, I use old Wekan version and make a lot of midification, so it's hard to move my Wekan application to new version. Unfortunately, the old Wekan is only on node 0.10.4x.

Comment: Well, you are in a pickle with that. Is it possible for you to merge your code with the latest version? It may take some effort, but at least it would give you a way forward

Comment: The code world is change very fast, the Wekan I use is just one year ago but it's seems already pass 100 years. I will try to merge my code to latest version. Thank you.

Comment: It can be solved by coping old node_modules to my Wekan project, the built code is runable for node 0.10.46. But it means that I cannot update my node_modules anymore.

Answer (score 1):

It seems, you're using really old version of `wekan` that needs such old version of node.

Unfortunately, `babel` transpiler (Meteor is using it to transpile JS code) has dropped support for Node 0.10 and 0.12 (discussed [here](https://github.com/babel/babel/issues/4315)).

I'd suggest you to update your `wekan` version or use [`nvm`](https://github.com/creationix/nvm) to install and use different version of `node` simultaneously.